# p5.js: loadFont not working with .ttf file from URL

Tags: javascript, fonts, processing, p5.js

I am tearing my hair out trying to get the `loadFont()` function to work in p5.js.

I've uploaded a font file to fonts directory in the root of my website and saved it as font.ttf, and I'm trying to load it in the preload function like this:

```
function preload() {
    font1 = loadFont("./fonts/font.ttf");
}
```

However when I load the page I just get "Loading..." in the top left forever. I've tried putting the font directly in the directory and calling `loadFont("font.ttf")`, but it never seems to load.

I suspect I am making a rookie error since I am very new to this, but I've trawled through everything I can find on the internet and this is apparently how it's supposed to be done. (https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadFont)

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Comment: Does this print anything useful to the console?

Comment: @MPawlak I've just checked (whoops, I completely forgot the console), I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'glyphIndexMap' of null`. I guess the font is not compatible or something.

Comment: Can you link to a copy of your code in the [P5.js editor](https://editor.p5js.org/)?

Comment: @Kevin Workman I am using the Processing editor in p5 mode since it doesn't seem possible to upload .ttf files on the web editor. I fixed the issue by using a different font, it seems that some fonts (that I had taken from my Apple computer `Library/Font` folder) didn't work. Now I am using Wingdings which loads, but then the characters are displayed as empty boxes!